# Why do the coordinate functions $x^1+W,\dots,x^n+W$ form a basis of $\mathscr{F}_p/W$?

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm a bit stuck in the following situation. Suppose $\mathscr{F}_p$ is the set of smooth functions $f\colon M\to R$ with $f(p)=0$. Also, let $W$ be the subspace generated by $fg$ for $f,g\in\mathscr{F}_p$.

On page 97 of Spivak's Diff. Geo., he mentions that $\dim(\mathscr{F}_p/W)^\ast=\dim(M)=n$, so $\dim(\mathscr{F}_p/W)=n$. Now by Lemma 2, if $x$ is a coordinate system, $x(p)=0$, then $x^1+W,\dots,x^n+W$ is a basis for $\mathscr{F}_p/W$.

Lemma 2 states:

> Let $f$ be a $C^\infty$ function in a convex open nbhd $U$ of $0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, with $f(0)=0$. Then there are $C^\infty$ functions $g_i:U\to\mathbb{R}$ such that
>   $$
> f(x^1,\dots,x^n)=\sum_{i=1}^n x^ig_i(x^1,\dots,x^n)
> $$
>   for $x\in U$, and $g_i(0)=D_if(0)$.

I take $x:U\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be be a coordinate system centered at $p$. Since $x(p)=0$, $x^i(p)=0$ for all $i$. The Lemma suggests to me that $x^1+W,\dots,x^n+W$ is probably a spanning set of $\mathscr{F}_p/W$, which suffices by dimensions, but I don't see how to twist the situation to apply Lemma 2. My hunch is that the $x^1,\dots,x^n$ span $\mathscr{F}_p$, so that their projections will also span $\mathscr{F}_p/W$, but the coordinate functions don't seem to fit the criteria of the Lemma?

I have been able to show that if $\ell\colon \mathscr{F}_p\to\mathbb{R}$ is linear with $\ell(fg)=0$, then it extends to a unique derivation, and the space of all derivations at $p$ is isomorphic to $(\mathscr{F}_p/W)^*$ if that's worth anything.

Comment: I'm a little confused about what your question is. Do you want to show that $\dim(\mathcal F_p / W) = \dim M = n$?

Comment: @GunnarMagnusson Sorry for being unclear, I don't understand why the images of the coordinate maps $x^1+W,\dots,x^n+W$ actually form a basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the problem is to show that the equivalence classes of $x_j$ in $\mathcal F_p / W$ actually generate that space and that linear independence is pretty much clear. To show this, we just have to take any function $f$ and develop it into a Taylor series to the second power (which is more or less what Lemma 2 does, step by step).

Let $f$ be a smooth function such that $f(0) = 0$. Then by Lemma 2 there are smooth functions $g_j$ such that
$$
f(x) = \sum_{j=1}^n x_j g_j(x)
$$
in a neighborhood of $0$. For each of the functions $g_j$, now play the same game with $h_j(x) = g_j(x) - g_j(0)$. Then we get functions $h_{j,k}$ such that
$$
g_j(x) = g_j(0) + \sum_{k=1}^n x_k h_{j,k}(x),
$$
which turns the original decomposition of $f$ into
$$
f(x) 
= \sum_{j=1}^n g_j(0)\,  x_j + \sum_{j,k=1}^n x_j x_k \, h_{j,k}(x).
$$
Now the second sum is definitely an element of $W$, so the equivalence class of $f$ in $\mathcal F_p / W$ can be written as a linear combination of those of $x_j$. Our original $f$ was arbitrary, so those classes span the space we're interested in.

Comment: Thank you Gunnar. What confuses me is should not $f$ be an arbitrary function in $\mathcal{F}_p$? If so, how do you know $f(0)=0$ to apply the lemma?

Comment: But I pick a function $f$ in $\mathcal F_p$ to begin with. I assumed $p = 0$ but there's no loss of generality there since we can change variables to $y = x - p$.